# Sum index in function collides with input variable

Tags: functions, indexing

When I enter the following:

```
Clear["Global`*"]
Func[f_, xx_] := Sum[D[f, xx[[s]]], {s, 1, 2}]
Func[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]
Func[x^2 + s^2, {x, s}]
```

The first function evaluation works fine. The second gives the error "General: 2 is not a variable". The following expression appears in the stack trace, which makes it pretty clear why this happens:

$$ \sum_{s=1}^2 \partial_{(x,s)[[s]]} (s^2 + x^2)
$$

The input variable $s$ is colliding with the sum index $s$.

It's pretty clear that I could avoid this by either

1. Using very obscure index names so I'm unlikely to ever use then when calling the function later.
2. Use normal index names but then take care to avoid using these as variables later on.

Neither of these seems ideal. Is there any way to "isolate" the sum index so that it won't collide with the input variables?

Comment: You could scope `s` using `Module`. `Func[f_, xx_] := Module[{s}, Sum[D[f, xx[[s]]], {s, 1, 2}]]`

Comment: Discussion about the need to localize the variables in `Table` and `Sum` can be found in [Do Table iteration variables need to be localized using Module?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94061/142).

Comment: Thank you both! This solved my problem

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can just use

```
Func[f_, xx_] := Total@Grad[f, xx]
Func[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}]
Func[x^2 + s^2, {x, s}]
```

> 2 x + 2 y
>
> 2 s + 2 x

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but computing the gradient was just an example - I was hoping for a generally applicable solution.