# Does lower case n have some significance in the Wolfram Language?

Tags: list-manipulation, neural-networks, iterators

I am truly confused with this one, and maybe someone could help me to clear this up.

I am running a `Table[]` that runs multiple neural networks in series on OpenAI's open gym for reinforcement learning. In my program, when `Table[]` is configured with `n` as the iterator, like the following:

```
Table[evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole[population[[n]], session, numberFrames], {n, Length[population]}]
```

The output is the following, where the values are incorrect because they are far too low (there is some slight variation in output each time within a few integer values due to the nature of OpenAI's gym):

```
{9., 8., 9., 8., 9., 10., 9., 10., 9., 10., 8., 10., 10., 10., 9., \
9., 10., 10., 10., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 10., 9., 9., 9., 9., 10., \
9., 10., 10., 11., 10., 8., 9., 9., 10., 10., 10., 9., 10., 8., 9., \
8., 10., 9., 10., 10., 8., 10., 10., 10., 9., 9., 10., 9., 8., 9., \
10., 10., 10., 10., 8., 10., 9., 10., 8., 9., 9., 9., 8., 9., 8., 9., \
9., 9., 10., 10., 10., 9., 9., 9., 10., 11., 8., 10., 9., 10., 9., \
10., 9., 9., 8., 9., 8., 8., 8., 10., 10., 9., 10., 10., 9., 10., 8., \
9., 10., 9., 9., 10., 9., 9., 10., 10., 9., 10., 10., 10., 8., 9., \
8., 9., 9., 9., 10., 10., 8., 10., 9., 9., 9., 8., 9., 10., 10., 9., \
10., 9., 9., 9., 10., 8., 8., 8., 9., 9., 8., 9., 8., 10., 10., 9., \
10., 10., 9., 10., 9., 10., 10., 9., 10., 10., 10., 9., 10., 9., 10., \
9., 9., 8., 10., 10., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 11., 10., 9., 9., 9., 10., \
9., 10., 9., 9., 9., 10., 10., 9., 9., 10., 10., 9., 10., 10.}
```

Where none of the values ever are over `11`. However, if I change the iterator to `x`, then the code works as I originally expected:

```
Table[evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole[population[[x]], session, numberFrames], {x, Length[population]}]
```

Giving:

```
{48., 13., 10., 100., 59., 44., 10., 9., 9., 12., 9., 13., 14., 36., \
100., 10., 10., 10., 46., 42., 8., 11., 9., 10., 10., 9., 25., 30., \
33., 81., 18., 11., 100., 9., 32., 29., 14., 9., 11., 58., 8., 13., \
15., 9., 9., 9., 60., 83., 100., 10., 10., 9., 12., 22., 10., 14., \
10., 100., 14., 34., 9., 37., 36., 28., 22., 12., 26., 67., 12., 9., \
18., 70., 49., 10., 8., 10., 33., 16., 15., 11., 9., 13., 21., 40., \
23., 9., 20., 9., 11., 76., 36., 44., 9., 9., 30., 19., 41., 47., \
18., 11., 38., 41., 9., 55., 14., 10., 54., 16., 41., 76., 10., 56., \
10., 9., 11., 10., 11., 11., 13., 9., 10., 11., 8., 9., 20., 53., \
13., 9., 43., 10., 17., 29., 9., 10., 8., 10., 9., 27., 14., 15., \
29., 23., 8., 77., 12., 10., 56., 13., 10., 65., 38., 19., 27., 15., \
13., 16., 10., 9., 86., 100., 9., 12., 8., 10., 10., 38., 9., 36., \
49., 54., 11., 14., 17., 17., 37., 28., 39., 10., 20., 15., 10., 10., \
25., 58., 10., 9., 100., 48., 10., 31., 25., 56., 17., 9., 16., 50., \
15., 10., 10., 35.}
```

Does anyone know what may be causing this? As more background, `n` does not have any values saved to it. Performing `Clear[n]` makes no difference in the strange outputs. I do have some other functions that use `n` as an iterator, but they are within `Module[]`s and are just used as iterators in functions like `Table[]`.

Any help on this would be very much appreciated, as I feel I must be missing something with this one.

EDIT:
For those interested, here is all of the code pertaining to the error I am getting. I have, as mentioned, been able to solve the problem by just replacing n with x, but still do not know why n is not working as intended:

```
numberOfInputs = 4;
numberOfOutputs = 1;
populationSize = 200;
numberFrames = 500;
structure = {100, Tanh, 100, Tanh, numberOfOutputs, Tanh};
session = initializeCartpoleSession[];
population = (time = UnixTime[];
   Table[SeedRandom[time + x];
    NetInitialize@NetChain[structure, "Input" -> numberOfInputs], {x, 
     populationSize}]);

(*Initialize the Python session which will be used for OpenAI Gyma*)
initializeCartpoleSession[] := Module[{session},
  session = StartExternalSession["Python"];

  ExternalEvaluate[session,
   "import gym
   env = gym.make('CartPole-v0')
   env.reset()"];

  ExternalEvaluate[session,
   "def runCartPoleOnce(action, env):
      observation, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
      return observation, reward, done, info"];

  session
  ]

(*Send in an action of left or right (0 or 1) and get the reward and \
state output as a result*)
runCartPoleOnce[session_, action_] := Module[{},
  ExternalEvaluate[session, 
   StringJoin["runCartPoleOnce(", ToString[action], ",env)"]]
  ]

(*Take a network and run it through the simulation for numberFrames \
frames*)
evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole[network_, session_, numberFrames_] := 
 Module[{action, reward, input},
  (*Reset the state of the cartpole*)
  action = 
   Normal[network[ExternalEvaluate[session, "env.reset()"], 
       TargetDevice -> "GPU"]][[1]] /. n_Real -> If[n < 0., 0, 1];

  Total[Total[
    Table[
     action = 
      Normal[network[{input, reward} = 
           runCartPoleOnce[session, action][[;; 2]]; input, 
          TargetDevice -> "GPU"]][[1]] /. n_Real -> If[n < 0., 0, 1];
     reward
     , {numberFrames}]
    ]]
  ]

(*Evaluate all the networks in the population, returning their \
fitnesses*)
evaluateOnePopulation[population_, session_, numberFrames_] := 
 Module[{},
  Table[evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole[population[[n]], session, 
    numberFrames], {n, Length[population]}]
  ]
```

Even running on a different kernel, when I run:

```
evaluateOnePopulation[population[[;; 10]], session, numberFrames]
```

I get back:

```
{9., 8., 10., 9., 9., 9., 9., 9., 10., 10.}
```

However, when I switch `n` to `x` in:

```
(*Evaluate all the networks in the population, returning their \
fitnesses*)
evaluateOnePopulation[population_, session_, numberFrames_] := 
 Module[{},
  Table[evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole[population[[x]], session, 
    numberFrames], {x, Length[population]}]
  ]
```

And run the same command again, I get:

```
{45., 10., 8., 10., 10., 40., 10., 10., 59., 10.}
```

Which is the expected result, as the values are no longer limited to being 11 or lower. Could this be a bug, or is there something I am overlooking?

Comment: It is hard to know without seeing the definition of `evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole` -- I suggest you try to devise a minimal example that illustrates the problem.  Perhaps it is the issue described in [Do Table iteration variables need to be localized using Module?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94061/142)

Comment: No, `n` is does not have a buiIt-in meaning. I propose to restart the kernel with `Exit` and to to again.

Comment: As is, there are *not* a lot to go by; some observations/suggestions: **1.** there are exactly 3 instances of `11` in the first list instead of *none*; the corresponding number in the second list is 11 **2.** the first list *appears* as a lower bound of some sort of the second list (using `ListLinePlot` helps) **3.1.** if I'd have to guess, what you're dealing with is *probably* some kind of premature convergence **3.2.** From the code, there doesn't seem to exist something that suggests `n` is somehow relevant to the problem. **4.** Try using other iterator symbols and see what happens

Comment: I have edited the question to include the details of the program, so one can try and recreate the error. Sorry it is not more brief but, seeing as how I am not sure what is causing the error, this is the most compact version I could currently give.

Comment: @WReach - It turns out that your suggestion worked - I went through and localized n to the modules in which it was used and the program now works - thanks! I was not aware that Table[]  does not localize variables automatically.

Answer (score 3):

As suggested by WReach, I added `n` to the `Module[]`s local variables and that solved the problem:

```
(*Evaluate all the networks in the population, returning their \
fitnesses*)
evaluateOnePopulation[population_, session_, numberFrames_] := 
 Module[{n},
  Table[evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole[population[[n]], session, 
    numberFrames], {n, Length[population]}]
  ]
```

Now, when I evaluate:

```
evaluateOnePopulation[population[[;; 10]], session, numberFrames]
```

I get back the intended results:

```
{9., 9., 9., 76., 60., 10., 10., 61., 10., 10.}
```

Comment: My guess is that `evaluateSingleNetworkOnOnePole` or a function it calls uses `n` but does not localize it as it should.

Comment: @MichaelE2 I agree - I also made sure to localize n in the other functions as well.