# Does any know how to get the paths of current opened locations in file explorer?

Tags: files-and-directories, windows, .netlink

Does anyone know if there is a builtin way to get all opened locations in the file explorer?

Like for browsers, the browser itself remembers the last opened locations. So even if it crashes one can restore them. But for file explorer, once the processes crash for some reason there is no way to get that information back.

Maybe there is some `Developer` context function or maybe someone knows how to get this information using the `NetLink` functionality? So I can periodically store them in my notebook so I don't lose them.

Comment: What is the file explorer? If you mean the interface for picking a file that Mathematica will open up, then I’m pretty sure the answer is no. That’s implemented by the OS so both the OS and Mathematica would need to expose some API and I’m not sure if either of them do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are referring to the Windows File Explorer, then we can use `NETLink` and the [Shell API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-reference-bumper) to get a list of open windows:

```
Needs["NETLink`"]
InstallNET[];

shellWindows[] :=
  NETBlock@Module[{app, windows, w, item}
  , Internal`WithLocalSettings[
      app = CreateCOMObject["Shell.Application"]
    , windows = app@Windows[]
    ; Table[
        Internal`WithLocalSettings[
          item = windows@Item[w]
        , item@Name -> item@LocationURL
        , ReleaseCOMObject[item]
        ]
      , {w, 0, windows@Count-1}
      ] // GroupBy[First->Last]
    , Scan[ReleaseCOMObject, {windows, app}]
    ]
  ]
```

This function retrieves an association of the names and file URLs of all open shell windows, grouped by their names.  File Explorer windows will all have the name *File Explorer* on Windows 10 (or *Windows Explorer* on earlier versions of Windows).

For example:

[image: shellWindows screenshot]

This function will also return entries for other shell windows that happen to be open, such as *Internet Explorer*.  But such entries will be grouped under other keys.

Comment: I have a few questions, does the manual release of COM objects necessary? Doesn't the `NETBlock` automatically release them when it ends? Secondly, what is the purpose of ``Internal`WithLocalSettings``? Thirdly, is `UninstallNET[]` needed to completely close all connections? Fourthly, once you release the COM object calling any of its methods obviously fails but is there a function to check whether COM object bound to a WL symbol is active or has been released? Finally, is there a function to get all the method names for the `COM` object?

Comment: Also, was the localization of `w` necessary? Isn't it automatically localized since it is a `Table` variable?

Comment: `NETBlock` only releases .NET objects.  COM objects need manual release.  `WithLocalSettings` is used to ensure the release even if an error occurs within the body.  `UninstallNET` can be used if you know you are done with all .NET interaction.  I usually leave it open for the whole session.  I do not know of a way to test a released COM object.  The only ways I know to get a list of COM methods is to read the docs (which I did here) or inspect the type library (if you have one available).  Yes, `w` is [necessary](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/94061/142).

Comment: Thank you @WReach for the answers! Do you also know how to get the list of all currently running programs being displayed on the windows taskbar? If you want I can open a new question.

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but you might start from something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1366356/211232).

Comment: can you please send me the link to the Docs page which lists the entire "Shell.Application" objects their member functions available for scripting. I can't find a page that lists them exhaustively.

Comment: The link I provided in my post was broken.  I have fixed it.  It links now to the proper [Shell reference pages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-reference-bumper).  The particular property I am using is [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/shell-windows).

Comment: Hi @WReach can you look at my current [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/270451/how-to-get-excel-cell-dependents-from-other-sheets-in-the-same-workbook). You know the `NETLink` stuff well!