# Unexpected result with sums in set delayed functions

Tags: algebraic-manipulation, scoping

I don't know if I've just found a bug (and if so, whether there's a workaround), or if I'm just losing my mind. Without further ado, here is my code (really, a minimal working example), run on Mathematica 12.0:

```
In[1]:= F[j_] := (r^2 + z^2 - 1) Sum[(-1)^k Binomial[2 j + 2, 2 k + 1] z^(2 (j - k) + 1) r^(2 k), 
    {k, 0, j}]

In[2]:= G[j_] := Sum[(-1)^(k + 1) F[k], {k, 0, j}]/(
 4 (j + 1) (j + 2) (2 j + 3))

In[3]:= G[3]

Out[3]= 1/720 (-2 z (-1 + r^2 + z^2) + (-1 + r^2 + z^2) (-4 r^2 z + 
      4 z^3) - (-1 + r^2 + z^2) (6 r^4 z - 20 r^2 z^3 + 6 z^5) + (-1 +
       r^2 + z^2) (-8 r^6 z + 56 r^4 z^3 - 56 r^2 z^5 + 8 z^7))

In[4]:= G[j]

Out[4]= -(((1 + (-1)^j + 2 r^2 - 2 (-1)^j r^2 + r^4 + (-1)^j r^4 - 
    6 r^(4 + 2 j) - 2 j r^(4 + 2 j) + 2 r^(8 + 2 j) + 
    2 j r^(8 + 2 j)) z (-1 + r^2 + z^2))/(
 4 (1 + j) (2 + j) (3 + 2 j) (-1 + r^2)^2 (1 + r^2)^2))

In[5]:= % /. j -> 3

Out[5]= -(((4 r^2 - 12 r^10 + 8 r^14) z (-1 + r^2 + z^2))/(
 720 (-1 + r^2)^2 (1 + r^2)^2))
```

The point of Out[5] is just to drive home the already-obvious point that Out[4] is not going to be correct. Indeed, it's not just 3: if I plug *any* (specific) value of j in, I get a correct answer that does not agree with G[j]. And why does G[j] have r's in the denominator anyway?!

I keep wondering if I'm just missing something obvious, which sometimes happen when I stare at code for a very long time.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. The title makes it a bit difficult for users to know what the problem is about and for users in the future to find this question. It could be better if keywords like sum and  function definition were in the title like "Unexpected result with sums in set delayed functions".

Comment: For the record, the original title of this post was "Bizarre behavior -- losing my mind", and the view count was 800 after 20 hours, far above average. It was also tweeted and all of that. The title of this post was just replaced by a more sober title, whereby "Bizarre behavior -- losing my mind"  has become available for some new question :)

Comment: @user293787 ohhh I wondered if it got on social media as I noticed an unusual number of views after only a few hours. I was planning to comment that I change my mind on my first comment given the apparent success of the title then I changed my mind. Not sure what the community bot is or how it managed to change the title to the suggestion I gave.

Comment: Sorry about my unspecific title! I'm fine with it having been changed. I agree it was unhelpful.

Comment: recently read https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/221151/86543 which seems relevant to mention here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To avoid unintended variable capture, one can use

```
F[j_]:=Module[{k},
         (r^2+z^2-1) Sum[(-1)^k Binomial[2 j+2,2 k+1] z^(2 (j-k)+1) r^(2 k),{k,0,j}]];
G[j_]:=Module[{k},
          Sum[(-1)^(k+1) F[k],{k,0,j}]/(4 (j+1) (j+2) (2 j+3))];
```

for example. Now

```
G[3]-(G[j]/.{j->3})//Simplify
(* 0 *)
```

---

Concerning `r` in the denominator, consider the much simpler case of a [geometric sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum):

```
Sum[r^k,{k,0,j}]
(* (-1+r^(1+j))/(-1+r) *)
```

Of course it is a polynomial for every fixed positive integer `j`.

Comment: Thank you! This worked!

Comment: If you don't mind my asking -- what *is* variable capture? (I googled it, but did not find anything.)

Comment: I think it is called variable capture;) see [this](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/66070) for example. Your code uses "the same" `k` in both sums. I think that was causing the problem, though I did not analyze how exactly. The `Module` just make sure that the `k` in `F` and the `k` in `G` cannot interfere.

Comment: Oh I see. Wow. Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

*I decided to move my comment from @user293787 to an answer as it made the comments a bit cluttered and made it unlikely that someone else encountering this issue would read it. I emphasize however that the answer that follows relies on user293787's explanation that there was conflict between the two k variables.*

A simpler case where that happens :

```
 Clear[F,G];

 F[j_]:=Sum[j,{k,0,j}];

 G[j_]:=Sum[F[k],{k,0,j}];

 G[3] == G[j]/.j->3
```

output:    `(* False *)`

**TL;DR** quick solution : You can use `F[j_]=` instead of `F[j_]:=` to avoid that problem.

[**Edit: added the solution below that localizes the iterator in a convenient way.**

More general solution : we can automatically localize all the iterators by defining a new sum and restricting the name choice for the iterators to belong to a set of one or more names.

Defining a sum that localizes the iterator k :

```
unique = Inactive@*Unique;
local = k -> unique[k];
sum = ReplaceAll[#, Activate@local] &@*Inactive[Sum]
```

One could probably include more iterators in  "local" using local={k1->unique[k1],k2-> unique[k2],...}. Then instead of using Sum the user may define F and G using the new sum function :

```
    Clear[F,G]
F[j_]=sum[j,{k,0,j}];
G[j_]= sum[F[k],{k,0,j}];
```

We can check that the iterators are correct by evaluating G on a symbolic argument:

[image: sum]

Finally we may check that the problem has been solved using sum:

```
G[t] == G[3] // Activate // ReplaceAll[t -> 3]

 (*True*)
```

**End of Edit**]

**TL;DR** **Origin of the problem**: symbolic handling of F[k] in G[j] where k appears in the argument of F and also in the iterator of the sum in the definition of F.

The solution above that consists of replacing `:=` with `=` evades the double presence of k by simply evaluating the sum so that k no longer appears (see discussion below if difference between := and = is not clear (nothing fancy)).

The symbolic handling occurs when the upper bound for the iterator in G (the last element of the second argument in `Sum`) is symbolic but not when it is an integer. This leads to a difference between `G[3]` and `G[j]/.j->3`. The solution

**The problem is tricky and interesting and it could be quite difficult to debug in a long code.**

#### Explanation

Pictorial summary and reference for the discussion below using traceView2 from this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29340/86543) (the images and discussion below will focus on the definitions of F and G of the simpler example above and should not be confused with the original F and G from the original question. Also, the discussion below does not require the reader to understand the images below):

[image: G3]

[image: G[j]]

Consider first `G[3]`.

From `traceview2[G[3]]` (output shown in first picture), one sees that the evaluation process is as expected:

```
G[3]=F[0]+F[1]+F[2]+F[3]
```

Consider now G[j] with a symbolic j. Mathematica does not know the upper bound in this case so it can not do:

```
F[0]+F[1]+...
```

Instead, as can be checked using traceView2[G[j]] (second image), Mathematica attempts to do pure symbolic manipulations replacing F[k] by the symbolic expression it gets from the definition of F, that is, the output of F[k], but...

```
F[k]
```

evaluates to

```
Sum[k,{k,0,k}]
```

which according to Mathematica is k(1+k)/2 but according to Mathematics, it is an invalid request.

The issue there is that maybe Mathematica applies the formula `Sum[k,{k,0,n}]` then takes n=k at the end where k is a global variable.

**So,**

Computing F[j], we obtain the expected result j(j+1) and then replacing j by k with `/.j->k`, we find a result that is different than the result obtained from `F[k]`.

---

**Ok, but why did that not happen with `G[3]` ?**

```
Attributes[Sum]
```

output: {HoldAll, Protected, ReadProtected}

For the following mini-discussion that answers the above question,the important component in the above output is HoldAll.

Sum holds F[k] meaning F[k] is not replaced by its definition right away. Instead at the beginning, basically, Mathematica sees the string of characters "F" "[" "k" "]" without checking what is under the hood (at least conceptually not sure what Mathematica is actually doing).
Then using the iterator k in the second argument of Sum, Sum successively makes replacements for k, k->0; `F[0]`, k->1; `F[1]`, k->2; `F[2]`, k->3; `F[3]` and each `F[0]`,`F[1]`,`F[2]`,`F[3]` will be replaced by its definition (I do not know if replacement rules are actually being used).

When the upper bound is symbolic that sequence can not happen and so F[k] is evaluated with a symbolic k

---

**Solution:**

If instead `F[j_]=Sum[k,{k,0,j}]` (no :=) then there are no surprises because the sum is evaluated before assigning the expression to the function F. Hence, Mathematica sees `F[j_]=j(j+1)`.

So a possible solution for the initial question of OP would be (replaced F[j_]:= with F[j_]=) :

```
Clear[F,G];
F[j_]=(r^2+z^2-1) Sum[(-1)^k Binomial[2 j+2,2 k+1] z^(2 (j-k)+1) r^(2 k),{k,0,j}];
G[j_]:=Sum[(-1)^(k+1) F[k],{k,0,j}]/(4 (j+1) (j+2) (2 j+3));
```

#### Appendix: Difference between `F[j_]=` and `F[j_]:=` and when to use one or the other (nothing fancy in the discussion below).

If I remember well, for a somewhat long time working with Mathematica I thought I always had to define a function with the construct `F[j_]:=expression`.

However, often it is better to use `F[j_]=` either to avoid surprises like in the above example or to increase the speed of execution as `F[j_]:=` means nothing is being evaluated until it is called with an argument. For example, compare (* The second one takes 2 seconds before it outputs something*):

```
Clear[f];AbsoluteTiming[f[j_]:=(Pause[2];Print["that took a long time"])]

Clear[f];AbsoluteTiming[f[j_]=(Pause[2];Print["that took a long time"])]
```

I use `f[j_]:=` when a symbolic expression can not be obtained or I need a black box numerical function for certain numerical computations in which case I would use `f[j_?NumericQ]:=`.

Comment: Note that `=` (as opposed to `:=`) is also prone to unexpected behavior, as in `i=4;(*lots of code*)f[i_]=i;f[12]` which returns `4`. The root cause of OPs problem is the fact that `Sum`, `Table`, `Integrate` and friends use dynamical scoping for the iteration variable, effectively using `Block`, which is a deliberate design choice of Mathematica in order to (I think) comfort the casual user that expects `f=Exp[-x]; Integrate[f,{x,0,1}]` to just work. People that do actual programming in Mathematica should be wary of this and always appropriately localize variables.

Comment: @user293787 Thank you. I would imagine that that example with i=4 is mainly a source of potential errors in the environment of an automatically executed script or package. In an interactive environment such as a notebook, the user is likely to notice the color change of the variable after assigning it a definition. An experienced user would then probably avoid using that letter. The only example in a notebook where I could imagine that problem might occur  is when manipulating very complicated expressions where the variables are hidden in the complexity.

Comment: That said, I was thinking earlier about a convenient way to localize the variables without having to use Module each time which is a bit tedious. I will edit my answer with the solution I found but while we are on the topic of localizing variables, the reader might be interested in this [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/37924/86543) that localizes all variables in a cell

Comment: Thank you very much for all of this. It's interesting and I didn't realize this was how things worked.

A philosophical question: was the original behavior a bug? Certainly it seems almost inconceivable that the behavior would ever be *desired* (but is that wrong?), and so at least as a design issue, I wonder if there should not be some kind of default assumption that iterator-type variables are dummies? But it is reassuring to know that it flows from consistent application of rules, at least, and perhaps there are great reasons for the rules that I do not fully understand.

Comment: @stuart Hi, not localizing all the variables might have been a design choice to make it more convenient for the user as user293787 mentioned in the first comment above but I don't know.

Comment: @stuart Dynamic scoping (`Block`) tends to be more difficult to reason about than lexical scoping (`Module`), see [this for Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559) or [this more generally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/321000). Note that `Sum`, `Integrate`, ... effectively use dynamic scoping. If you think this design is weird, you could ask a new question about it. Perhaps other versions of `Sum`, `Integrate`, `Table`, ... that use lexical scoping are available somewhere, that would certainly be useful.

Comment: @user293787 Thank you. This [question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11579/86543) also has interesting uses for Block which might be an example of the benefits of that design. Also, maybe the edit I added below "TL;DR, quick solution" which uses Inactive and Unique could also  be used for `Integrate` and `Table` to localize the iterators.