# Internal variable in Sum inside a function

Tags: functions, summation, variable

I am writing a simple function which performs a sum, but run into an unexpected answer.

```
f[n_]:=Sum[n-m, {m, 1, 10}]
f[1] (* gives -45 *)
f[m] (* gives 0; didn't expect this *)
```

It appears that when fed an unassigned `m`, `m` coincides with the iteration variable `m`, which if of course is **undesired**. I can change the iteration variable to something like `$m`. But is there better practice to force the iteration variable to be completely local? Perhaps I should use `Module` or `Block`?

(`Module` seems to do the job)

Comment: This is [documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sum.html), see "Details and Options": The iteration variable is effectively localized using `Block`, which leads to the behavior that you describe. Yes, you can use `f[n_]:=Module[{m},Sum[n-m,{m,1,10}]]`. You write that the default behavior "of course is undesired" but if you think about it... there are cases where this is exactly the behavior that some users expect. See [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/273476/85954) for example.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unexpected result with sums in set delayed functions](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/273476/unexpected-result-with-sums-in-set-delayed-functions)

Comment: There is a metaphor from physics to understand the scoping of `Module (With)` vs. `Block`: `Module` localizes variables in a spatial way while `Block` in a temporal way.

Comment: @user64494 Yes it does. Thanks!