# How to define a version of Table[] which localizes iteration variable by Module[]?

Tags: list-manipulation, scoping, hold, meta-programming

For reusable code it's good practice to use `Module[]` to localize iteration variables used by `Table[]`, as explained by this [post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/94061/do-table-iteration-variables-need-to-be-localized-using-module).

Is it possible to use some Hold / ReleaseHold gymnastics to write a function `ModuleTable[]` which behaves like this?

```
ModuleTable[f[i], {i, 1, 10}]
```

gets automatically expanded into

```
Module[{i}, Table[f[i], {i, 1, 10}]]
```

Comment: In the simplest case of a single iteration variable, what you ask for is as simple as `SetAttributes[ModuleTable, HoldAll]; ModuleTable[code_, iter : {var_, __}] := 
 Module[{var}, Table[code, iter]]`. Generalizing to several iteration variables is not hard either.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I figured out how to handle any number of iterations. `SetAttributes[ModuleTable, HoldAll]; 
ModuleTable[code_, iters : ({_, __} ..)] := 
 Module[Evaluate[{iters}[[All, 1]]], Table[code, iters]];`

Comment: @felix not so simple though, try `i = 5; ModuleTable[i, {i, 10}]`

Comment: @Kuba You're right. Do you have a quick solution? It's easy to deal with a fixed number of 2 iterations, 3 iterations etc., but I haven't figured out how to do it for an arbitrary number of iterations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is one way to do this for arbitrary number of iterators:

```
ClearAll[ModuleTable]
SetAttributes[ModuleTable, HoldAll];
ModuleTable[code_, iters__List] :=
  Replace[
    DeleteCases[Hold[iters][[All, 1]], Except[_Symbol]], 
    Hold[vars__] :> Module[{vars}, Table[code, iters]]
  ]
```

where `DeleteCases` was necessary since iterators may not include a symbol. The main device to control code evaluation, used here, is called [injector pattern](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1929/injecting-a-sequence-of-expressions-into-a-held-expression/1937#1937) on this site (you can search for this term to see other examples of its use).

For example:

```
ClearAll[a, b]
a = 1;
b = 2;
ModuleTable[a + b, {a, 1, 3}, {2}, {b, 2, 5}]

(* {{{3, 4, 5, 6}, {3, 4, 5, 6}}, {{4, 5, 6, 7}, {4, 5, 6, 7}}, {{5, 6, 7, 8}, {5, 6, 7, 8}}} *)
```